# Assign ON to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If I assign `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` variable and then print it in Windows Command Prompt as follows:

```
set Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON
echo %Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS%
```

an empty line is displayed.

And I get an error in some script that requires the variable to be exactly "ON":

```
* libboost_system-vc143-mt-s-x64-1_80.lib (static runtime,
Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME not ON)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The subsequent error is because you set the wrong variable, not because the the assignment went wrong.  Compare `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` vs `Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is set correctly, but "echo ON" is a shell command to turn echo mode on or off and has no output.  Try any of the following:

```
set Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON

if %Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS%==ON echo yes
echo it is %Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS%
set Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS
```

Output:

```
yes
it is ON
Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON
```

Comment: `echo(ON` - the `(` directly after `echo` forces `echo` to literally output the string thereafter (also useful to echo a possibly empty variable: `echo(%empty%` without error message). There are different chars you can use `=,/(`, but `(` turned out to be the most reliable. The others may fail in some strange circumstances.